# symfony2: image path from controller

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

Consider the following code in my controller:

```
 $array = array(
         array('src' => assetic_image('img/someimage.png')),
         array('src' => assetic_image('img/other.png')));
```

this raises the error:

`Trying to get property of non{-object`

how do I use assetic to reference a resource file from the controller ?

In other words, how do I get the path to an image from a controller ? (this does not have to use assetic necessarily....)

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15648505/779320

Comment: yes it looks like my question is a duplicate. Thank you. Mod-> could you mark it as duplicate ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Assetic get asset urls from inside controller, not template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644598/symfony2-assetic-get-asset-urls-from-inside-controller-not-template)