# Can't find image path inside Symfony controller

Tags: php, image, symfony

Inside my `Symfony2/web/img` directory is a file `del.png` which i want to display from within a controller.

I tried using functions like `image_path()` of `image_tag()` but Symfony tells me this are unknown functions...

It can be done with:

```
$html = "<img src='".$request->getBasePath()."/img/del.png' alt='Delete user' border=0>";
return $this->render ('myBundle:stats:menu.html.twig', array('html'=>$html));
```

or also like stated in [Symfony2 Assetic get asset urls from inside controller, not template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644598/symfony2-assetic-get-asset-urls-from-inside-controller-not-template/15648505#15648505)

but I think it can be done an easier way.  It seems sooo simple, so i'm probably forgetting something :-(
Any suggestions?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-images

Comment: @FDL, that's within a twig template.  I want to use it in a PHP file. ( {{ ... }} doesn't work there )

Comment: ... there are PHP examples too (in the tabs).

Comment: @FDL, I see, but where did you get the $view variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('img/edit.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) function

```
echo '<img src="'.$view['assets']->getUrl('img/del.png').'" alt="Delete user" border="0">';
```

Comment: where do you define/get the $view variable?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not writing this in a template but in a controller.

Comment: Why doing echo in a controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644598/symfony2-assetic-get-asset-urls-from-inside-controller-not-template

Comment: Correct, it was a wrong example.  In my controller i assigned it to html-code which goed to a template.  (clarified the question already)

Comment: I reffered tot that answer already in my question, but I can't believe this is the shortest way to archive it...